# Laravel use trans into string or Html package

Tags: php, laravel

Hi all i'm using `Html` package on laravel and i'm trying to use `{{trans()}}` into below code, but i could not do that and my result is php code

```
{!! Html::link('/password/email', "{{trans('strings.login_policies'))}}") !!}
```

or

```
{!! Html::link('/password/email', "trans('strings.login_policies')") !!}
```

My result:

```
<?php echo e(trans('strings.login_policies'))); ?>
```

how to use `trans` into this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `trans()` function can not find the translation it will output the parameter string as is provided.

Are you sure the file `strings.php` exists in `resources/lang/{defaultlocale}`? And make sure there is a key `login_policies` in this file. All information on how to work with translations can be found in the laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/localization).

#### Update

I didn't take a good look at your code, you don't need to use `{{` and `}}` to use a string directly in a function call, this is only needed to output data directly into blade templates. You can just use the `trans()` function directly like so:

```
{!! Html::link('/password/email', trans('strings.login_policies')) !!}
```

Comment: I haven't been using blade for a while, but doesn''t `{!!` escape the output for html? Should'nt it be just `{{ Html::link('..`?

Comment: It's the other way arround, `{{` will escape html and `{!!` will allow it.